# Laravel 4 authentication. Restrict access to some functions of a resource but not all

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have this blog resource which has the usual CRUD methods.(index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy).

I have the following route in my routes.php:

```
Route::resource('blog', 'PostsController');
```

but I want to restrict all but index and show.
so I have

```
Route::get('blog', 'PostsController@index');
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::resource('blog', 'PostsController');
});
```

which is fine for index but I don't know how to route the show method ? Or is there another  way? Instead of routing the resource should I route every URI individually and put the ones I want restricted in my restricted access route?

Cheers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Laravel has a feature that lets you specify filters in the controllers' `__construct` method using `$this->beforeFilter`. This function takes a second argument that lets your provide exceptions (or enable the filter only for certain methods). Try using your original routes file and set up your controller like this:

```php
class PostsController extends BaseController {

    function __construct() {
        // ...
        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => array('index', 'show')));
        // ...
    }

    // ...
```

See Controller Filters in the [Laravel documentation](http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers). It's not entirely well-documented, but you can also start a deeper journey into the guts of Laravel from [here](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Routing.Controllers.Controller.html#39-51).

Comment: Thank looks like a valid option

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Laravel is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5 you use middleware function instead like this:

```
$this->middleware('auth', array('except' => array('index', 'show')));
```